# Radical solution to a polynomial quartic equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider the following quartic equation:

$$x^4 + rx^3 + r^2x^2 + r^3x + r^4 - 1 = 0$$

By Lodovico Ferrari solution, this equation must possess four radical solution provided that $r$ is a rational number, my question is simply if we assume $r$ is an algebraic number (which is a more general set of numbers that contains all rational numbers), can this equation still possess four radical roots

Comment: The equation is not biquadratic. A biquadratic equation is of the form $ax^4+bx^2+c=0$. The equation $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$ is called a quartic.

Comment: Do you mean that the roots are radical for every algebraic $r$ ? Then the answer is no. Do you mean that for some algebraic irrational $r$ the roots are radical ? Then the answer is yes.

Comment: Actually as you mentioned I used to get radical roots for some algebraic (r), but suspected that can be generalised for any algebraic (r), also I re edited the question based on your valuable remarks

Comment: The question as it stands has a problem: it doesn't state which is the field over which it is considered. If the field is $\Bbb C$, then its roots will always be expressed as radicals. Further, Cardano's formulae are for equations of degree $3$, not $4$.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the equation are radical if and only if $r$ itself can be expressed by radicals.

Comment: If this is true, it would be a very elegant answer, is there a reference please?

Comment: One direction is easy : If $r$ is expressible by radicals, then the roots also are. I am not completely sure about  the other direction, but I cannot imagine a counterexample.

Comment: The galois theory should help, but unfortunately, I do not well understand it.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely true, unfortunately I can't upvote it, and if what you claim is the only condition (with proof) then it becomes a theorem

Comment: @bassamkarzeddin If the roots are expressible by radicals, then so are the symmetric functions of the roots. In particular $-r$ is the sum of the roots, and so is expressible by radicals.

Comment: I do not follow: the $4$th degree equation with complex coefficients is always solvable by radicals, irrespective of other properties of its coefficients. What am I missing?

Comment: If what you claim is generally true, then this would imply that Quintic equation is also solvable by radicals, but this would certainly contradict Galois theory! that is not obvious for me , At least I hope what you say is True?

Comment: My claim, of course, refers to the quartic equation.

Comment: @Peter, the OP's expression is quartic in both $x$ and $r$, so the "other direction" is more or less automatic:  If, for a given number $r$, there is a root $x$ that can be expressed in radicals (of rational numbers), then the quartic in $r$, using those radical expressions as coefficients, is solvable in radicals (because it's a quartic), and one of its four roots must be the original number $r$.